# How do I get checked boxes values from the placeholders?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating checkbox to placeholder. Its about to bus tickets. If bus has 50 seats, I create 50 checkboxes. Thats ok, but How I can get which checkbox is checked?

Can I put checked boxes an arraylist? I know dynamic controls removed after postback can I hold checked boxes id's with viewstate?

this is what I did
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SywcE.png

I want to redirect users when they checked number and click the button.

Comment: On button click the page will be postback or redirect?

Comment: I will recommend you to use javascript or jquery for this.

Comment: postback or redirect. no matter how I do.

Comment: are you okay to do this task using jquery?

Comment: I dont know how I do this with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

As you create each control, be sure to set its ID:

```
CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
c.ID = "checkbox_50";
```

You have to do this each time the controls are created.

When you need to get the values, use

```
bool checked = (Page.FindControl("checkbox_50") as CheckBox).Checked;
```